# WP Background Image display after content area

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way to display the background image after the content area, if that content area is short and doesn't cover all the height of the display?

This is the html and cs I'm using now. And here is an example http://asptmr.studyor.net/contact/

```
<body class="home blog custom-background">

body.custom-background {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("http://asptmr.studyor.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bg-11-full_2.jpg");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved using a wordpress [plug-in](http://pippinsplugins.com/simple-fullscreen-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your stylesheet, and the background will fill the screen:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You are right about that, but if the content exceeds the screen (so you have the scroll down) then the background image won't cover the whole content area.

Comment: True, I guess I was just looking at his example. Could you change `height` to `min-height`?